# Limit $\lim _{ h\to0 }{ \frac { \sin { 9h } }{ h } } $

Tags: calculus

$$\lim _{ h\to0 }{ \dfrac { \sin { 9h }  }{ h }  } $$

Steps I took:

$$let\quad \theta \quad =\quad 9h$$

$$\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ 9\left(\frac { \sin { 9h }  }{ 9h } \right) } $$

$$\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ 9\left(\frac { \sin { \theta  }  }{ \theta  } \right) } =9$$

So I arrived at the correct solution but then I started thinking about it. Why am I multiplying by $9$ if the part that I want to be multiplied by $9$ is the denominator. Shouldn't I have to multiply by $\frac { 1 }{ 9 } $ then?

Comment: The important thing to recognize is that the argument of the sine must match the divisor. You can accomplish that by putting an additional factor of $9$ in the denominator, but you must then compensate by putting a factor of $9$ in the numerator in order not to modify the value of the expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're multiplying by $9/9=1$ to preserve the identity of the ratio.

Answer (score 2):

If $\theta=9h$ then $$\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} = \frac{\sin(9h)}{9h}$$ so $$9\left(\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}\right) = \frac{\sin(9h)}{h}$$